# Measure the time difference of dataframe in accordance to index

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe which is of shape
df_total=

[image: df_total]

This is just the dummy table as the dataset is too long. I want to calculate the time difference with reference to Index. That is,

[image: df_time_diff]

How can I do that efficiently in python? Time difference can be in days or minutes.

Number of occurrence of Index 1,2 and so on are very different. (8000,375,...)

i tried the following:

```
df_total['diff'] = df_total.sort_values(['index','time']).groupby('index'['time'].diff()
df_total= df_total.dropna(subset=['diff'])
```

this give me difference at every instance while i need it per Index.

Comment: OCR is pretty good these days but please add sample data as text instead of image next time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of sorting, you can just take max-min for each index group;

```
# set index
df = df.set_index(df['Index'])

# make sure you have datetime dtype
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

# group by index
grouped = df.groupby(df.index)
# ... and take max-min
ptp = (grouped['Time'].max()-grouped['Time'].min()).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

```
ptp
Out[29]: 
Index
1    300.0
3     88.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

note that I have modified the sample data slightly, so that the propagation of Index is visible:

```
Index Time 
1 2020-03-30T13:00:00 
1 2020-03-30T14:00:00 
1 2020-03-30T15:55:00 
1 2020-03-30T18:00:00 
3 2020-04-03T09:00:00 
3 2020-04-03T09:50:00 
3 2020-04-03T10:28:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below groupby command to get the output in a single code.

Make sure **Time** column is a datetime

```
 df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
 df.groupby("Index")["Time"].apply(lambda g: int((g.max() - g.min()).seconds/60))
```

Hope this solves your query!

Comment: If you want to have the difference as decimals then please remove int(). `df.groupby("Index")["Time"].apply(lambda g: (g.max() - g.min()).seconds/60)`

Comment: note that `apply` (although it might look nice) introduced an unneeded iteration step

Comment: The answer is not correct for this implementation. Not sure why

Comment: It worked in my case. Can you share the error if possible?

Comment: @AshishJain No error. The minutes calculation is wrong